# Get response from POST with 302 status

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

jQuery File Upload:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: 'http://URL/images/pre/',
    add: function (e, data) {
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url : 'http://URL/images/pre/',
            dataType : 'jsonp',
            jsonp : 'jsonp',
            success : function(result) {
                url = result.url.replace(...);
                data.url = url;
                data.submit();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

data.submit() sends POST to appengine which returns 302 (redirect() from webapp.RequestHandler).
Is it possible to get response from this POST after redirection?

Comment: can use `statusCode` option of `$.ajax`...not clear what you are trying to achieve exactly

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the answer is that you can't. The ajax request will be transparently redirected and you will get the result from the final page.

Rather than doing a redirect, I would include the redirect location in the response data and respond with a normal 200 along with the data you want.